# Rails 4.2 will_paginate error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Trying to upgrade to Rails 4.2 from 4.1.8 and I'm getting a "wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)" for this line:

```
<%= will_paginate(@search) %>
```

Works perfectly find in Rails 4.1.8. @search is a custom object which defines the methods will_paginate needs (total_pages, etc).

The method signature for will_paginate is:

```
def will_paginate(collection = nil, options = {}) #:nodoc:
```

And I verified the proper method is being called by using:

```
<%= self.method(:will_paginate).source_location %>
```

Which outputted:

["/Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/will_paginate-3.0.7/lib/will_paginate/view_helpers/action_view.rb", 26]

Kind of stumped, and surprised that nobody else has encountered this issue.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the error *wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)* refers to that method call ? It states that you are providing 2 arguments

Comment: Yes, that is the line that is highlighted in red on the Rails error page with the proper line number and the page loads fine when I delete only that line.

Comment: what does `@search.class` return ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady that returns SearchResults which is a custom class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the bartt-ssl_requirement gem overrides :url_for in a way that is not compatible with Rails 4.2. Removing that gem resolved the issue.